# JavaScript: JQuery UI Tabs won't load my other HTML pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So problem is that i added Tabs from JQuery UI in my web, and now my tab which contains paragraphs loads fine but tabs on which i have linked to other html pages(which donot contain Tabs) , they wont load. here is the my .js file code and .html code:

```js
$(function(){
 $("#tabs").tabs(); 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title id="myTitle">Persistant Programmer: Testing Website</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script17.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.12.1/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css" />
  
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="game.html">Click-Picture Game</a></li>
    <li><a href="catgame/catGame.html">Feed the Cat Game</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Hello there! Welcome to my Website. My name is Syed Hammad Jaffery, studying in FAST-NUCES. Purpose of this site is just a playground for my JavaScript Codes. JavaScript is something which is really basic need in today's world, there couldn't exist any web which only runs with HTML5 and CSS3. We need JavaScript to give some living feature to our webpages on which they can act and do stuff dynamically <br></br>I know this web is really newbie version and possibly not even shown on Search Engines but still Thanks for visiting.</p>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I have placed game.html in the same folder as my this html file and catGame.html in a folder named catgame which is present in the same directory as of my html file.

It's been one day i am stuck on it, and i am really new in JavaScript took some tutorials online. Tried everything as it is from here http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax .

Thanks in Anticipation

Comment: anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, it is not possible directly using jQuery UI tabs.
You can do it with some jQuery tricks [as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377407/load-page-into-a-div-with-a-specific-jquery-ui-tab-selected)

Comment: But as you can see in the link http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax it gets done like that and in tutorial videos its same way.
And in the link you gave AmirhoseiN that person has setup things differently he didn't even calls .tabs()

Comment: I'm sorry, you are write, and I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: but in case of your problem, do you open page locally, or within a web server? AJAX calls needs to be served via web servers.

Comment: Thanks !. Now problem is resolved, there was no problem in script as soon as i used web server to run it , worked fine here you can see http://persistantprogrammer.000webhostapp.com/Hammad/plugins.html